# Order by field in another table in one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables - `orders` and `payments` in relation one-to-many in PostgreSQL DB.

I would like to order `orders` by `payments.status`.

Tried with following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (payments.id) orders.*
FROM orders
INNER JOIN payments ON orders.id=payments.order_id
ORDER BY payments.id, payments.status DESC
```

But with `INNER JOIN` it will reject records with missing `payments`.

I have also tried to do this with `OUTER JOIN` solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (payments.id) orders.*
FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN payments ON orders.id=payments.order_id
ORDER BY payments.id, payments.status DESC
```

But it also seems to cut some values no idea why.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @antesoles: a `left join` is **exactly** the same thing as a `left outer join`

Comment: If there is more than one `payment` per `order`, by the `status` of which `payment` should be sorted? If there is no `payment` for an `order`, how should that be sorted?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I would like to retrive latest payment if there are many payments and if payment is missing it should be treated as `null`

Comment: All orders with no payments will be represented by one order due to DISTINCT

Comment: But you do a `DISTINCT ON (payments.id)` which means you want all `payments`. I think you need `DISTINCT ON (orders.id) ... ORDER BY orders.id, payments.status DESC` (and `LEFT JOIN` OFC). -- And you can control orders without payments, like: `ORDER BY orders.id, payments.status DESC [NULLS FIRST|NULLS LAST]`.

Comment: @pozs I have tried this solution but it is ordering results by `orders.id` instead of `payments.status`

Comment: @Gregy yes, that the limitation of `DISTINCT ON`. If you want to order by the `MAX(payments.status)` first, you need to do aggregation. -- `DISTINCT ON (payments.id)` will never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (orders.id) orders.*, payments.status payment_status
      FROM orders
         LEFT OUTER JOIN payments ON orders.id = payments.order_id
      ORDER BY payments.create_ts DESC
   ) wrap
ORDER BY payment_status;
```

Here `payments.create_ts` orders the payments by time. If your `id` increases monotonically, you can use that instead.

`col1`, `col2`, `col3` are columns on the `orders` table – the list contains all columns, but not `payment_status`.

Comment: It works nearly perfect. But how can I get rid of payment_status field? I have tried to modify select to - `SELECT orders.*` but it throws `PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders"`

Comment: Well, replace the `*` with the names of the columns you want. Using `*` is a bad habit anyway.

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: If you omit the `payment_status` from the outer `SELECT`, it won't be in the result, right?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to only return sorted orders without information about payment_status

Comment: @Gregy you can do `SELECT DISTINCT ON (...) orders, ...` inside (note that there is no star) & `SELECT (wrap.orders).*` outside.

Comment: @Gregy Then just do it... I have updated the answer to make it clearer.